# Como hacer una query optimizada de unions?

Tags: sql

Hola tengo tablas con MILLONES de datos (literalmente) y estoy haciendo la siguiente query:

```
SELECT
    facturas.fac_pto_nro,
    facturas.fac_nro,
    facturas.fac_cdg_cod 
FROM
    megatone:informix.facturas facturas 
        INNER JOIN megatone:informix.ctes_garext ctes_garext 
        ON facturas.fac_com_cod = ctes_garext.cge_com_cod AND
        facturas.fac_pto_nro = ctes_garext.cge_cte_pto_nro AND
        facturas.fac_nro = ctes_garext.cge_cte_nro AND
        facturas.fac_cdg_cod = ctes_garext.cge_cte_cdg_cod 
    UNION
SELECT
    notas_credito.ncr_pto_nro,
    notas_credito.ncr_nro,
    notas_credito.ncr_cdg_cod 
FROM
    megatone:informix.notas_credito notas_credito 
    INNER JOIN megatone:informix.ctes_garext ctes_garext_1 
    ON notas_credito.ncr_com_cod = ctes_garext_1.cge_com_cod AND
    notas_credito.ncr_pto_nro = ctes_garext_1.cge_cte_pto_nro AND
    notas_credito.ncr_nro = ctes_garext_1.cge_cte_nro AND
    notas_credito.ncr_cdg_cod = ctes_garext_1.cge_cte_cdg_cod 
    UNION
SELECT
    notas_debito.ndb_pto_nro,
    notas_debito.ndb_nro,
    notas_debito.ndb_cdg_cod 
FROM
    megatone:informix.notas_debito notas_debito 
    INNER JOIN megatone:informix.ctes_garext ctes_garext_2 
    ON notas_debito.ndb_pto_nro = ctes_garext_2.cge_cte_pto_nro AND
    notas_debito.ndb_nro = ctes_garext_2.cge_cte_nro AND
    notas_debito.ndb_cdg_cod = ctes_garext_2.cge_cte_cdg_cod
```

A todo esto, tiene que ser paginado con un LIMIT 10, por ejemplo, que otra manera podria hacer para que solo me traiga 10 registros instantaneamente?

Comment: ¿La información devuelta tiene que estar actualizada en tiempo real? Si no es así podes crear una tabla, llenarla con el resultado de la consulta y trabajar sobre esta nueva tabla y sus registros. Cada cierto tiempo deberías actualizarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puesto que `UNION` elimina duplicados y solo estás consultando datos en la columna de clientes, podrías cambiar todo por un condiciones EXISTS. Así no necesitas eliminar duplicados porque no se generan. Obviamente, esto depende de que la sintaxis esté disponible en el producto que uses.

```
SELECT 
        cge_cte_pto_nro ,
        cge_cte_nro     ,
        cge_cte_cdg_cod 
FROM  megatone:informix.ctes_garext cg
WHERE EXISTS(  SELECT *
                FROM megatone:informix.facturas f
                WHERE f.fac_com_cod = cg.cge_com_cod 
                AND   f.fac_pto_nro = cg.cge_cte_pto_nro 
                AND   f.fac_nro     = cg.cge_cte_nro 
                AND   f.fac_cdg_cod = cg.cge_cte_cdg_cod )
OR EXISTS(  SELECT *
                FROM megatone:informix.notas_credito nc
                WHERE nc.ncr_com_cod = cg.cge_com_cod 
                AND   nc.ncr_pto_nro = cg.cge_cte_pto_nro 
                AND   nc.ncr_nro     = cg.cge_cte_nro 
                AND   nc.ncr_cdg_cod = cg.cge_cte_cdg_cod )
OR EXISTS(  SELECT *
                FROM megatone:informix.notas_debito nd
                WHERE nd.ndb_pto_nro = cg.cge_cte_pto_nro 
                AND   nd.ndb_nro     = cg.cge_cte_nro 
                AND   nd.ndb_cdg_cod = cg.cge_cte_cdg_cod );
```

Answer (score -1):

Una forma de optimizar la consulta y hacer que solo traiga los primeros 10 registros es utilizar la cláusula LIMIT en lugar de utilizar UNION. La consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
    facturas.fac_pto_nro,
    facturas.fac_nro,
    facturas.fac_cdg_cod 
FROM
    megatone:informix.facturas facturas 
        INNER JOIN megatone:informix.ctes_garext ctes_garext 
        ON facturas.fac_com_cod = ctes_garext.cge_com_cod AND
        facturas.fac_pto_nro = ctes_garext.cge_cte_pto_nro AND
        facturas.fac_nro = ctes_garext.cge_cte_nro AND
        facturas.fac_cdg_cod = ctes_garext.cge_cte_cdg_cod 
    LIMIT 10
```

De esta manera, la consulta solo va a traer los primeros 10 registros que cumplan con la condición especificada en el JOIN. Si queres obtener más registros, podes utilizar la cláusula OFFSET junto con LIMIT para especificar a partir de qué registro queres obtener los resultados. Por ejemplo, para obtener los siguientes 10 registros después de los primeros 10, podes utilizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
    facturas.fac_pto_nro,
    facturas.fac_nro,
    facturas.fac_cdg_cod 
FROM
    megatone:informix.facturas facturas 
        INNER JOIN megatone:informix.ctes_garext ctes_garext 
        ON facturas.fac_com_cod = ctes_garext.cge_com_cod AND
        facturas.fac_pto_nro = ctes_garext.cge_cte_pto_nro AND
        facturas.fac_nro = ctes_garext.cge_cte_nro AND
        facturas.fac_cdg_cod = ctes_garext.cge_cte_cdg_cod 
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Esta consulta te va a devolver los siguientes 10 registros después de los primeros 10. Podes utilizar esta técnica para ir pagando los resultados de la consulta de a grupos de 10 registros. Avisa si necesitas algo mas pa, saludo

Comment: si no ordenas la consulta, los 10 registros pueden ser distintos en cada ejecucion...